# AWS DynamoDB error: "The security token included in the request is invalid." although credentials are in shared security file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've placed correct (and recently updated to ensure they're valid) credentials in `~/.aws/credentials`

```
aws_access_key_id = xxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key = yyyyyyyy
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = zzzzzzzzzz
```

but when I make a call to DynamoDb

this.docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

```
 this.docClient.scan(params).promise().then(data => {
        console.log('data received',data)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error from scan',err)
    })
```

I get

> "The security token included in the request is invalid."

as the error from the scan.  Other DynamoDB calls fail there as well, with the same error.

I'm at a bit of a loss here, since it should work.  Can anyone suggest where I might look to track down the issue?

Comment: you meant `aws_session_token`, right ? `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` is used with `export` under env variable

Comment: @error404 Indeed, that was the error I think.  That's the format it came in -- with that variable capitalised -- when you generate it with the AWS dashboard and download the file.  I changed it to lower case and it seems to work fine now.  I want to test a little more before I mark this as 'answered'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding answer:

the variable used in the credentials file was wrong. credentials file expects the below vars to be defined.

```
aws_access_key_id =

aws_secret_access_key =

aws_session_token =
```

AWS_SESSION_TOKEN is the value to be used while exporting in the session.

```
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
```

Comment: It was an error in our own internal dashboard that is connected to the AWS dashboard: it produced the variable with capitalised letters.